# Hiding folder with RewriteRule [R=404] produces endless redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to hide my wp-admin folder using this nifty bit of code, but the problem is that if I don't have "XYZ" in my User Agent, it gets stuck in an infinte redirect loop:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 # Make wp-admin folder only visible to browsers with "XYZ" in the User Agent:
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !XYZ
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
</ifModule>
```

I understand that the R flag generates an external redirect, so I tried this hoping it would produce an internal redirect, with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]
```

Comment: R flag redirects depend on the substitution URL. ¿What's `XYZ`, are you sure that parameter doesn't apply to all agents?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you could use the `[F]` flag, to make the page forbidden.

Comment: You need to send the user outside the current folder. Where is your 404 error document?

Comment: Gerben: Yeah, 403 just confirms they got the right path.

Comment: Wige: It's /wp-content/themes/xyz/404.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the user outside the current directory. I would move the rules to the root directory of the site, as follows:

```
# Keep user out of your error document folder as well
RedirectMatch 404 /errordocs
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 # Make wp-admin folder only visible to browsers with "XYZ" in the User Agent:
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !XYZ
 RewriteRule ^wp-config/(.*)$ errordocs/404.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

This way you can redirect the user into another folder. Otherwise you get loops and other issues when you try to redirect the user from within the folder.

Comment: Thank you Wige.  This sounds very sensible.  I'll give it a try.